# How to manually construct an Scala runtime AST that instantiates a Class?

Tags: scala, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-reflect

I am having trouble constructing correct Scala (2.13.3) syntax trees at runtime. Suppose we define the following class.

```scala
class Foo(x: Int)
```

I would like to construct the syntax tree for the following line of code.

```scala
new Foo(1)
```

For reference, we can generate the correct syntax tree using `ru.reify`. We can also type check this tree to confirm it is valid.

```scala
val expectedTree = ru.reify {
    new Foo(1)
}

println(ru.showRaw(expectedTree))
// Apply(
//     Select(
//         New(Ident(my.package.Foo)),  <-- What does Ident hold here?
//         termNames.CONSTRUCTOR
//     ), 
//     List(
//         Literal(Constant(1))
//     )
// )

val toolbox = mirror.mkToolBox()
toolbox.typecheck(expectedTree).tpe
// my.package.Foo
```

However, if I cannot figure out how to properly code the same syntax tree from scratch. Below is my initial attempt. I also tried the same thing with `TermName` instead of `TypeName` and see the same result.

```scala
import ru._

val actualTree = Apply(
    Select(
        New(Ident(TypeName("my.package.Foo"))),
        termNames.CONSTRUCTOR
    ), 
    List(
        Literal(Constant(1))
    )
)

println(ru.showRaw(actualTree))
// Apply(
//     Select(
//         New(Ident(TypeName("my.package.Foo"))), <-- Ident holds a TypeName
//         termNames.CONSTRUCTOR
//     ), 
//     List(
//         Literal(Constant(1))
//     )
// )

val toolbox = mirror.mkToolBox()
toolbox.typecheck(actualTree).tpe
// ToolBoxError: reflective typecheck has failed: not found: type my.package.Foo
```

The `actualTree` is obviously not valid because it doesn't type check. If we inspect the printed output, we can see that the `Ident` appears to be different between the `expectedTree` and the `actualTree`.

From the API, it seems like `Ident` must hold a `Name` object, but I cannot figure out which kind of name is required here. Furthermore, the printed output of the `expectedTree` doesn't indicate that the `Ident` is holding a `Name` at all. Is this some other kind of `Ident`? What would the proper code be to manually construct the AST of `new Foo(1)`?

EDIT:
I was asked to supply information on why quasiquotes and/or reify don't work my use case. The short answer is: this is research tech in automatic programming.

The research task is to synthesize a correct using only a test suite. I am implementing a Scala version of [the recently published method called "Code Building Genetic Programming"](https://arxiv.org/abs/2008.03649).

I understand the warnings against manual construction in typical reflection use case but I believe the other construction methods require some notion of what the program/AST should be at development time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides extractor's `apply` metod accepting a `Name`

```
abstract class IdentExtractor {
  def apply(name: Name): Ident
  //...
}
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L1787

there is also factory method accepting a `Symbol`

```
def Ident(sym: Symbol): Ident
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Trees.scala#L2237

Try

```
val actualTree = Apply(
  Select(
    New(Ident(typeOf[Foo].typeSymbol)),
    termNames.CONSTRUCTOR
  ),
  List(
    Literal(Constant(1))
  )
)

println(ru.showRaw(actualTree)) 
//Apply(Select(New(Ident(my.package.Foo)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR), List(Literal(Constant(1))))

println(toolbox.typecheck(actualTree).tpe) // my.package.Foo
```

Quasiquotes and `reify`/`splice` are [preferable ways](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html#creating-trees) to construct trees. So you should provide more details why `q"new my.package.Foo(1)"` and `ru.reify { new Foo(1) }.tree` are not enough for your use case. Normally it's not necessary to build identical trees, it's enough to build trees that behave as desired (but there are exceptions).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer the Ident factory that takes type symbols. I am not sure why my editor didn't find that one. Also, I added an explanation of my use case to the main question.