# How to define a class at runtime that includes a call to a method of an object without a companion class?

Tags: scala, reflection, abstract-syntax-tree, scala-reflect

The following Scala (2.12.12) code runs with the expected behavior. The `ClassDef` tree is defined using the toolbox, and a `ClassSymbol` is returned.

```scala
class MyObj

object MyObj {
  def foo(x: Int): Int = x
}

object Test {

  import ru._

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    val objSymbol = ru.typeOf[MyObj].typeSymbol.companion  // This is the most important line!

    val tree = ClassDef(
      Modifiers(),
      TypeName("Program"),
      List(),
      Template(
        List(Ident(TypeName("AnyRef"))),
        noSelfType,
        List(
          DefDef(
            Modifiers(),
            termNames.CONSTRUCTOR,
            List(),
            List(List()),
            TypeTree(),
            Block(
              List(
                Apply(Select(Super(This(typeNames.EMPTY), typeNames.EMPTY), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR), List())
              ),
              Literal(Constant(()))
            )
          ),
          DefDef(
            Modifiers(),
            TermName("fn"),
            List(),
            List(),
            TypeTree(),
            Apply(Select(Ident(objSymbol), TermName("foo")), List(Literal(Constant(10))))
          )
        )
      )
    )

    val clsSymbol = Reflection.toolbox.define(tree).asInstanceOf[ClassSymbol]
  }

}
```

However, the `class MyObj` is only serving the purpose of allowing us to get the symbol of the object via `ru.typeOf[MyObj].typeSymbol.companion`. I have some situations where an `object` does not have a companion class, and I would like to modify this code so that it works without the need for `class MyObj`.

Here is what I have tried so far:

---

**Attempt 1.**

`val objSymbol = ru.typeOf[MyObj.type].typeSymbol`

Produces the following error in the compiler. I don't know how to understand it, and can't find many mentions of this kind of error outside of the Scala language developer discussions.

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.tools.reflect.ToolBoxError: reflective compilation has failed:


  Unexpected tree in genLoad: erp12.scala_cbgp.lang.MyObj.type/class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeTree at: NoPosition
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: jvm
     library version: version 2.12.12
    compiler version: version 2.12.12
  reconstructed args: 

  last tree to typer: TypeTree(class Int)
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: Int
              symbol: (final abstract) class Int in package scala
   symbol definition: final abstract class Int extends  (a ClassSymbol with SynchronizedClassSymbol)
      symbol package: scala
       symbol owners: class Int
           call site: constructor Program in class Program in package __wrapper$1$78b0f9d262f74777a2e9b5209fcd5413
```

---

**Attempt 2.**

`currentMirror.staticModule(MyObj.getClass.getCanonicalName)`

Also tried with variations:

- `runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)` vs `currentMirror`
- `MyObj.getClass.getTypeName` vs `MyObj.getClass.getCanonicalName` (same thing in this case)

This throw a `ToolBoxError` with `value foo is not a member of object erp12.scala_cbgp.lang.MyObj$` which leads me to believe it is returning a different symbol from the one I need.

---

**Attempt 3.**

`currentMirror.staticClass(MyObj.getClass.getCanonicalName)`

Yields the same result as attempt 1.

---

Any guidance on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you really sure reflection is the best solution to your meta problem?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez The code example in the question is not representative of my meta problem, but rather a distilled snippet to demonstrate a generic question about Scala reflection as a whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close.

The issue with **attempt 1** is that `ru.typeOf[MyObj.type].typeSymbol` is the `ClassSymbol` of this object, not its `ModuleSymbol`. So try

```
ru.typeOf[MyObj.type].typeSymbol.asClass.module
```

instead. See details in [Get the module symbol, given I have the module class, scala macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121612/get-the-module-symbol-given-i-have-the-module-class-scala-macro)

The issue with **attempts 2-3** is that `MyObj.getClass.getCanonicalName` is `path.to.MyObj$` but this is a Java-style name, not Scala-style one. You can now try just to drop a dollar sign

```
currentMirror.staticModule(MyObj.getClass.getCanonicalName.stripSuffix("$"))
```

but this works not always. See details in [In a scala macro, how to get the full name that a class will have at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64472135/in-a-scala-macro-how-to-get-the-full-name-that-a-class-will-have-at-runtime) (with comments). So better would be

```
currentMirror.staticModule(
  // Scala-style name i.e. path.to.MyObj
  currentMirror.moduleSymbol(MyObj.getClass).fullName 
)
```

or just

```
currentMirror.moduleSymbol(MyObj.getClass)
```

By the way, I'd write your tree with a quasiquote

```
val tree = q"""
  class Program {
     def fn = $objSymbol.foo(10)
  }"""
```

although I [remember](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603394/how-to-manually-construct-an-scala-runtime-ast-that-instantiates-a-class) that you prefer manual construction.